# Tikz: draw over gridlines

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-arrows

I am currently creating an axis with

```
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-0.5, xmax=3.5,
ymin=-0.5, ymax=3.5,
axis on top,
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
]
```

and I draw arrows within this axis using

```
draw[red,thick,->] (axis cs:1.2,1) -- (axis cs:1.8,1);
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

**How do I draw the arrows such that they are drawn covering the gridlines?**

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
    xmin=-0.5, xmax=3.5,
    ymin=-0.5, ymax=3.5,
    axis on top,
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids
    ]
    \draw[red,thick,->] (axis cs:1.2,1) -- (axis cs:1.8,1);
    \draw[red,thick,->] (axis cs:2,0.2) -- (axis cs:2,0.8);
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the obvious answer of "remove `axis on top`" not an option?

Comment: Yeah... I should definitely spend more time thinking about what I copy and paste around than on asking stupid questions....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual says of the `axis on top` key:

> ```
> /pgfplots/axis on top=true|false                               (initially false)
> ```
>
> If set to `true`, axis lines, ticks, tick labels and grid lines will be drawn on top of plot graphics.

Hence, all you have to do is remove `axis on top` from the list of options for the `axis` environment.